# template<typename A B>

Tags: c++, templates

What does `template<typename A B>` mean? `template<typename A, typename B>` means template with two types but what does the first one mean?
I saw this kind in STL Set Class.
 Specifically

```
template <class _Key, 
          class _Compare __STL_DEPENDENT_DEFAULT_TMPL(less<_Key>),
          class _Alloc = __STL_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR(_Key)>
class set;
```

Comment: Hi Vinay! If you found an answer useful, could you accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it? It expresses to the community that you have found a satisfactory answer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a macro that either evaluates to something like `= less<_Key>` or nothing depending on whether your compiler supports default template arguments.

Comment: In general is there any meaning for template<typename A B> ?

Comment: @Vinay No, assuming `A` and `B` are not macros, `template<typename A B>` is a syntax error.